# Sqoop - NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Tags: sqoop, mysql-connector

Am trying to connect sqoop (1.4.7) to Server version: 8.0.29-0 on ubuntu0.22.04.2 using
mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar on a hadoop-3.3.3 system.Have placed the .jar file in sqoop's lib folder but unable to connect. The error is as follows

```
Warning: /home/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.7/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.7/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.7/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.7/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
2022-06-10 20:50:12,792 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2022-06-10 20:50:12,815 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2022-06-10 20:50:12,919 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.initOptionDefaults(MySQLManager.java:73)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also download Apache `commons-lang` JAR file, since that contains the class that is reported in the error, not any MySQL classes.

Please note: Sqoop is a retired Apache project, and it's suggested to find other alternatives.